# How to say python scheduler to run a thread after finishing a function in django?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, scheduler

I want to call a function inside one of my views in another thread to avoid blocking the user request. But when I tried it using threading.Thread I got the same result as running single thread. Can anybody help me with this problem?

```py
def my_view(request):
    print()
    threading.Thread(target=foo)
    return HttpResponse('ok')


def foo():
    # blocks for 10 seconds
```

Comment: Consider using a task queue like Celery or RQ instead of writing your own threading code.

Comment: Your snippet creates a thread but never runs it. Please post a proper minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)